# Recursive merge sort that just takes length of the array as parameter

Tags: c, recursion, mergesort

I mostly understand the recursive merge sort function that takes in an array, a low integer, and a high integer. However, I was curiously trying to write a recursive merge sort function that just takes in the length of the array. The signature is: `void merge_sort(int *array, int n);` This proved a lot harder than I thought is was going to be.

I'll post the code below, but my function (I think) is only splitting the the first half of the array for every call to merge_sort(), essentially not touching the second half of the array (again, I think).

Another issue im having is, when copying everything from the auxiliary array back into the original array (using a for loop), I'm not sure what to use as my initial condition for the loop. Below is the recursive merge sort I've written that takes in a low and a high value, and then below that is the merge_sort that just takes in the length.

```
// Takes in low and high value
void merge_sort(int *array, int lo, int hi)
{
  int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2, i = lo, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

  // Auxiliary to store sorted values.
  int *aux = NULL;

  // Base case.
  if (lo >= hi)
    return;

  // Recursive calls.
  merge_sort(array, lo, mid);
  merge_sort(array, mid + 1, hi);

  // Mergy merge.
  aux = malloc(sizeof(int) * (hi - lo + 1));

  if (aux == NULL)
    return;

  while (i <= mid || j <= hi)
  {
    if (i > mid || j <= hi && array[j] < array[i])
      aux[k++] = array[j++];
    else
      aux[k++] = array[i++];
  }

  // Copy everything from the auxiliary array back into the original array.
  for (i = lo; i <=hi; i++)
    array[i] = aux[i - lo];

  free(aux);
}
// Takes in length of the array.
// This is very wrong, but I quickly tried to rewrite
// how I originally tried to tackle this problem
// when I first attempted it for this post.
void merge_sort(int *array, int n)
{
  // Auxiliary to store sorted values.
  int *aux = NULL;

  // Base case. Single element left in the array.
  if (n/2 < 1)
    return;

  // Recursive calls.
  // First call should take in the first half of the array.
  merge_sort(array, n/2);
  // This call should set the base address of the array 
  // to the midpoint of the array.
  merge_sort(array + n/2, n/2);

  // Mergy merge.
  aux = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));

  if (aux == NULL)
    return;

  while (i <= n/2 || j <= n)
  {
    if (i > n/2 || j <= n && array[j] < array[i])
      aux[k++] = array[j++];
    else
      aux[k++] = array[i++];
  }

  // Not sure how to write this part of the function correctly. 
  // Low is changing with each call to 
  // merge_sort(array, lo, hi), but in this function there is 
  // no lo variable
  //for (i = *lo*; i <= n; i++)
  //  array[i] = aux[i - lo];

  free(aux);
}
```

Edit: My goal for this is to try an eliminate any off-by-one errors when calling merge sort.

Comment: By the way, I love this part of your code!  
 ```if (i >= n/2 || j < n && array[j] < array[i])
      aux[k++] = array[j++];
    else
      aux[k++] = array[i++];```

Comment: @MohamedAkram Thank you! Learned it from my cs professor a small while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my changes //@

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void printArr(int*arr,int n,char c){
  printf("array of size %d: ",n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
  }
  printf("%c",c);
}
void merge_sort(int *array, int n)
{
  // Auxiliary to store sorted values.
  int *aux = NULL;

  // Base case. Single element left in the array.
  if (n/2 < 1)
    return;

  // Recursive calls.
  // First call should take in the first half of the array.
  merge_sort(array, n/2);
  // This call should set the base address of the array 
  // to the midpoint of the array.

  //@ till the end of the array: n - n / 2 (for odd initial size of array)
  merge_sort(array + n/2, n -n/2);

  // Mergy merge.
  //@ n is enough not n+1
  aux = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));

  if (aux == NULL)
    return;
  
  //@start i from 0, j from n / 2 and k from 0
  int i = 0;
  int j = n/2;
  int k = 0;
  // while (i <= n/2 || j <= n)  
  //@ till k fills the whole array from 0 to n
  while(k<n)
  {
    //@ i condition i>=n/2 not i>n/2 also, j condition j<n not j<=n
    if (i >= n/2 || j < n && array[j] < array[i])
      aux[k++] = array[j++];
    else
      aux[k++] = array[i++];
  }

  //@ now aux has the true values for array, from 0 to n so just loop and copy
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   array[i] = aux[i];

  free(aux);
}
int main(){
  int arr[] = {3,2,6,1,8,9,4,7,5};
  merge_sort(arr,9);
  
  printArr(arr,9,'\n');
  
  return 0;
}
```